# How should a leader handle advice giving?

Tags: leadership

From time to time I have a situation where a middle manager I'm leading isn't seeing an issue or isn't engaging creatively to solve a problem.

How do I go about giving advice without eliciting defeat/irritation/patronisation from the manager?

We all know what it's like to have the insufferable boss that has all the great ideas. How do we, as leaders, share in ideas without becoming that insufferable leader?

Comment: possibly related: [How can I keep myself from overstepping my authority with co-workers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/23772/168) "Giving advice is really slippery road, it implies that you know better than someone, better enough to guide them. This may be perceived negatively..."

Comment: Ask him to go through the task. Ask him how he plans to do things and why. Once you get into it it's quite easy to just suggest an alternate possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Discuss issues first, ideas and solutions later.**

During your meetings with the middle manager you lead, I would focus on the issues and problems that exist in their team. Ask questions and listen actively. Try to direct the conversation into the areas you believe require his attention, to see if they are aware of the issues himself. Ask what *they intend* to do in this particular situation, leave advice for later stage.

Sometimes an important issue really goes over their head. In that case, address the matter directly (*"I noticed that recently..."*), and again ask what they intend to do and how their plan will make the situation better. Get back to them about the issue frequently, let them describe the steps they took and how the situation improved. If the issue fails to improve, reiterate the importance of the subject matter to you. You're the manager, you set priorities.

Ultimately, you are his supervisor. In this case, the line between "advice" and "instruction" is quite thin. Don't forget that as a manager you have to sometimes cross the line to address more important issues, if your middle manager fails to do so. Use your intuition and approach each situation individually.

Comment: Thanks Neo. Another thing shared with me recently was the necessity for your team to feel comfortable about brutal honesty in both directions. If people don't feel safe to push back, then you'll have a tough time getting a sense of people's buy-in and engagement.